# Laura's coconut secret

Tags: plot-explanation, twin-peaks

I'm watching through the weird Twin Peaks series. If you remember, Laura Palmer, in one of her tapes to Dr. Jacoby, talks about her secret coconut (or secret in the coconut, maybe). What did she mean by that? At first I thought it was the half-necklace that ends up with Dr. Jacoby, but he only gets the necklace after Laura dies, when Donna and James bury it.

There are some other holes in the story, but for some reason, this one kept bugging me. Any ideas?

Comment: It's been a while, but I thought *her* half was in the coconut and James' half was recovered from the woods.

Comment: Actually, I think OP's right: The first half was found on her body, the second half was buried and then recovered by Jacoby. It's possible she meant she knows he hides stuff in there (there was also a tape in it). Maybe a rewatch in preparation for the new season is in order.

Comment: There are a lot of things that kept bugging me but never thought much about this one.

Answer (score 4):

When Donna and James snoop around Jacoby's office, they look inside the coconut and find not only the necklace but one of Laura's tapes. It's just as unlikely that Laura was referring to that particular tape, but this establishes the coconut as a place where Jacoby hides things, possibly things that relate to Laura specifically.

If we imagine that Laura was referring to some other secret that used to be hidden in the coconut, like an earlier tape, then there is no plot hole. Out-of-universe, though, it's not impossible that the writers got their timeline scrambled and forgot that Laura wouldn't know about the tape or the necklace.